# What is Causing AngularFire authState behavior?

Tags: ionic-framework, angularfire2

I am new to both AngularFire and Ionic. I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.paulhalliday.io/2017/09/08/ionic-3-and-firebase-user-authentication/) to add Firebase Auth to my ionic project.

HomePage is the root page. It checks the authState to determine if the user is logged in or not. If not, it redirects to the LoginPage. On successful login, it once again sets the HomePage as root. It is not working as expected.

Here are the logs from the console:

```
Not logged in. Navigating to login page.
login.ts:27 ionViewDidLoad LoginPage
home.ts:22 User logged in. UID: taiNC6n64BP4gD8jTcnXUu53npc2
home.ts:22 User logged in. UID: taiNC6n64BP4gD8jTcnXUu53npc2
2home.ts:27 Not logged in. Navigating to login page.
login.ts:27 ionViewDidLoad LoginPage
login.ts:27 ionViewDidLoad LoginPage
```

Relevant code on the home page:

```
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(res => {
        if (res && res.uid) {
            console.log("User logged in. UID: " + res.uid);
            //Do nothing
        } else {
            //Push them to the login page
            console.log("Not logged in. Navigating to login page.");
            this.navCtrl.setRoot('LoginPage');
        }
    });
}
```

Code from login page:

```
async login(user: User){
    try {
        const result = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
        if (result) {
            this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
        }  
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

As you can see from the logs, it correctly shows that the user is logged out of the app on the initial load and redirects to the login page. The home page is then reset as root. The `authStat.subscribe` is being hit 4 times. And the second two times the user is no longer available. What is causing this and how can I make the login persistent? According to the AngularFire docs, the default behavior is persistent login.

**--UPDATE--**

I tried the solution below. Now my logs look like this:

```
ionViewDidLoad HomePage
app.component.ts:26 Not logged in.
login.ts:27 ionViewDidLoad LoginPage
app.component.ts:23 Logged in.
home.ts:24 ionViewDidLoad HomePage
home.ts:24 ionViewDidLoad HomePage
app.component.ts:26 Not logged in.
login.ts:27 ionViewDidLoad LoginPage
```

And the code in my app.component.ts file:

```
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage:any = 'HomePage';

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
      this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user){
          console.log("Logged in.");
          this.nav.setRoot('HomePage');
        } else {
          console.log("Not logged in.");
          this.nav.setRoot('LoginPage');
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by multiple subscriptions to the authstate observable. Also make sure to unsubscribe onDestroy.

Comment: It is better to add this as a comment.

Comment: Indeed. It was ment to be a comment. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score -1):

Try to check the login condition in app.component.ts file of your project and first set the root page to any. After checking the login condition, set the root page. Here is a screenshot for reference.

[image]